# How to login to Google via selenium if the locators are scrambled?

Tags: selenium, google-signin

We have a webapp requiring the user to login, via a Google login page. As I understand it, the locators are apparently scrambled so you can't sendKeys to them by finding the element. Even though it looks like you should be able to identify the element by id or type attribute. Eg:

```
<input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your email" name="identifier" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">
```

What you can do, on Chrome desktop browser, is sendKeys to the browser itself (given that the username and password field are active).

Eg:
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys("MrUser").perform();

This doesn't work on Android Chrome however, where the login fields are initially inactive.

What options have you tried to getting selenium to interact with the Google signin page cross-platform?

Comment: Post your actual code attempts and what each result was. As far as I've seen, they aren't scrambled enough to prevent their usage.

Comment: Actually we're seeing different behaviour today - we can today access the Google sign in elements fine. But successive session attempts to access the Google sign in page itself, when clicking our 'login to google' button, by automation, seem not to function, unless you wait a small period in between attempts. So this original issue is for the moment resolved. Thank you.